# Unable to inject javascript using selenium 3 in firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am injecting java script variables using selenium and retrieving it for verification.

Below is my sample code, which was working fine with selenium version 2.53.1.
When I upgraded to selenium 3 and started to use gecko driver for firefox, it throws exception when I am retrieving value.

```
driver.executeScript("globalVar='Amit';");
Object result = driver.executeScript("return globalVar");
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: globalVar is not defined
```

In selenium 3 same code also working for Chrome.

Am I missing anything here? Or is there any capabilities added to allow such things in Firefox/Gecko driver?

Comment: In which line of code this error occurred??

Comment: While retriving value:

Object result = driver.executeScript("return globalVar");

Comment: try once as `driver.executeScript("window.globalVar='Amit';");
  Object result = driver.executeScript("return window.globalVar");
  System.out.println(result.toString());`

Comment: Yes window and document is alternate for that, but what is the reason this is not working in firefox, or in which object the firefox stores the injected variable?

Comment: For example if I want to inject jquery then I can't change  all the variables and function, this should be working.

Comment: Which firefox version you are using?

Comment: Firefox 50.0.2 and gecko driver version:0.11.1

Answer (score 0):

*The variables you set in a script that you execute are not global* - they are "sitting" in the scope of the executed function. If you want to have a global variable that you want to access across multiple executed scripts, you have to use one of the available global objects, e.g. `window`:

```
driver.executeScript("window.globalVar = 'Amit';");
Object result = driver.executeScript("return window.globalVar");
System.out.println(result.toString());
```